# Flutter - Row items space increases with the page zoom in case of Border

Tags: flutter, dart, row, border, grid-layout

I think there is a bug in Row and Column in flutter as you can see from the image attached below. I was creating a custom calendar and noticed that there is a small space between some items that varies with the screen resolution. So i tested it on the Web with the built in layout editor and i found the same bug.
If i change my page zoom the space comes and goes according to my zoom percentage as you can see the picture.

[image]

[image]

I need the solution to this problem as i am stuck on this last problem.

Comment: Why did you guys considered the question as unclear or useless there is a clear bug in the flutter you can try this on your own machines to test it.

Comment: If you think the question needs update then suggest it. otherwise acknowledge that it is a bug